# How to remove a particular text in TextInput in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textinput

Design  a Text Input by using components in flash and its InstanceName is listChat. In that text input I added a text by Dynamically. While I am adding text it displays with null.

For Example I added "apple" it Displays like nullapple

How to  remove that null?

Comment: i added the text by Dynamically,using SharedObject.i Cleared my Shared Object,So SharedObject the returns null.Its Correct,thats not my Problem.But How to remove the "null" text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the String's `replace` method.

If you want to remove only the first encounter of 'null' you can use this:

```
listChat.text = listChat.text.replace("null", "");
```

If you want to remove all encounters of 'null' this will do it:

```
var stripNullPattern:RegExp = /null/gi;
listChat.text = listChat.text.replace(stripNullPattern, "");
```

If you only want to remove null if it's in the first four characters use something like this:

```
if(listChat.text.substring(0, 4) == "null")
{
    listChat.text = listChat.text.replace("null", "");
}
```

Check the AS3 reference for more info:

[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29)

Comment: Good explanation, but I suspect a different issue, not related to the string trimming.

Comment: So you wanted to eliminate ANY null occurrence?

Comment: ya, u Didn't Under Stand My Question sir?Sorry

Comment: Well, it lacked informations about SharedObject and you did not mention you wanted to replace any "null" occurrence. But @rvmook understood you well, so I think it was my problem.   :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5531/discussion-between-victory-and-asthewormturns)